# Chrome Extension v3 - Making HTTP Request to http://localhost from the background.js

Tags: google-chrome, http, request, manifest

Working on a chrome extension which uses v3 manifest. Extension is loaded from an unpacked local directory. Want to make an HTTP GET(or POST) request to a locally running server. Server is available at http://localhost:2233.
In the background.js I do:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function() {
    fetch('http://localhost:2233/api/v1/version')
            .then(res => {
                console.error(JSON.stringify(res.json()))
            })
});
```

The result is empty "{}" in the logs.

"Service worker inspector" shows successful request and response.

In the manifest contains the host permissions:

```
"host_permissions": [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "http://localhost/*",
    "http://localhost:2233/*",
    "*://*/*"
]
```

Seems to be some manifest/permission issue. Would appreciate help making the request and getting the data from the locally running server.